# Vue localforage no update

Tags: vue.js, localforage

I'm using localforage, but I can't figure out why this.emails is not updated outside the localforage. I get no errors in console.

```
localforage.getItem("emails").then(function (value) {
                        this.emails = value
                        console.log(value)   // shows correct value
                        console.log(this.emails) // shows correct value
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err); // no error is thrown
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have a `this` scope. So when you're setting `this.emails`, you're setting the function's `this.emails` instead of your Vue component.

You could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to deal with this, but the easier way would be to just use an anonymous function in your `then`, like this:

```
localforage.getItem("emails").then((value) => {
    this.emails = value
})
```